# How to select data in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, select, insert

I have a problem. I try to select data from my database table, and i just want to select the name data, this is how i select the data:

```
$name = DB::table('users_data')->select('name')->where('number', $number)->get();
```

After that i store the $name variable to the database again, but what i get in my database is like this:

```
[{"nama":"Daniel"}]
```

What i want is just the name (Daniel). How can i do that?, help me, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Use [->value()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#retrieving-results) method

```
$name = DB::table('users_data')->where('number', $number)->value('name');
```

*Check for column name `nama` or `name`.*

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get only 1 value from the database then use:

```
$name = DB::table('users_data')->where('number', $number)->value('name');
```

If you want to retrieve a collection then use

```
$name = DB::table('users_data')->where('number', $number)->get()->pluck('name');
```